# Advanced image search in private cloud

Tags: owncloud, nextcloud

I want to install my own cloud instead of Google Drive/Images, but in Google images you can find your pictures not only by filename - if you type 'dog', google will show all your dogs images.

Is there is something like that in ownCloud or NextCloud?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such thing available for Nextcloud and I guess also not for ownCloud.

There is some interest from the community in implementing this (https://help.nextcloud.com/t/search-images-power-by-ai-with-python/40641). However, a good implementation will probably be a challenge since there isn't much existing code or libraries written in PHP available.

I'm not an expert on this field, but an "advantage" for these big companies, is that they have lots of data available to train or test their AI. However, I guess for most people running Nextcloud, this will be just another reason to skip these services :) .